# Old group policy screen lock stuck

Tags: windows-8.1, group-policy, screensaver

My old sixth form college enforced some of their own policies when you linked a personal device with their email accounts. This included (a) maximum 15 minute screensaver delay and (b) compulsory screen lock after screensaver. I've long since left the college, and removed the account from my PC, but this policy remains.

I'm on standard windows 8.1, so don't have access to group policy editor, in itself or through MMC.

How can I get rid of this wretched policy?

edit: I can change the fields in the screensaver settings window, but ticking/unticking the lock option has no effect, and a screensaver delay greater than 15 minutes will revert to 15 minutes upon exiting the menu.

Comment: Not sure if this will have an effect, but its worth a try. Open a command prompt and type `gpupdate /force`

Comment: Unfortunately, no success with that. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: If you're using Windows 8.1 non-pro, then it couldn't have been affected by group policies as Pro is a requirement to be controlled by GP. Also when GPOs are controlling those settings you won't be able to change them at all (they'll be greyed out).  You MAY be getting affected by Active Sync polices. Have you removed your school email account from Windows Mail?

Comment: In hindsight, I think it probably was active sync causing it, but I removed the account from windows mail, contacts, etc quite some time ago.

Comment: Your comment re active sync reminded me of a past issue I had - I've been quite the fool. It's fixed by going control panel -> user accounts -> reset security policies. That's it - done. 

Thanks for all your help on the issue.

Comment: @HarrySargent: You should add that as an answer below, which you can also self-accept after 2 days.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It's fixed by going control panel -> user accounts -> reset security policies.